# Heroku assets:precompile generating things that shouldn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

We've recently started using Heroku for hosting our Rails apps.  We're using the asset_sync gem to upload compiled assets to Amazon S3, which is working well.  However, I noticed that a lot of garbage files were ending up in the bucket, so I dug a little deeper.  At first I thought asset_sync wasn't removing the files correctly when syncing, but it now looks like Heroku's assets:precompile process is generating assets from files that no longer exist.

Files that have been deleted from the source and committed are still showing up in Heroku's asset output, despite deleting tmp files and running assets:clean.  I've ensured that the files do not exist in our project's Heroku repository.  Running assets:precompile locally in production mode does not produce those same unwanted files.

Any ideas?  We're new to Rails, so we're not sure if this common, or an issue with Heroku or our Rails app setup.

Comment: This question does not provide adequate information in order to be able to debug it. Can you show us what you mean by "garbage files"? Maybe you still have them committed to Git?

Comment: As I said, files that no long exist in the apps asset folder are showing up in the output of assets:precompile. They are not in th repo (they've been cleanly removed in a commit) and I've made sure to clear the cache and tmp folder on the Heroku server.

Comment: To clarify, there is no example.png in the images folder, but one is showing up in public/assets

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what could be causing this then. It might do you to contact support@heroku.com